# central one-time initialization on application startup

Tags: java, android

is there a place where I can execute some initialization java code on application startup outside `MainActivity.java`?

It can be a non-activity based java file, just to have it run static initializers.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final ConfigItems...

    static {
        // initializing script
    }

}
```

I could have done it in `MainActivity` too but I've learned that even `MainActivity` can get killed too by the `Android OS` in case of low memory, and if `MainActivity` comes back alive again it will repeat the static initializer code which I don't want.

I could add some `if/else` within static initializer to check if it was previously initialized but looking for something cleaner, something specifically meant just to do that, i.e. one time initializer.

I can't use strings.xml for that, it's sort of dynamic nature and requires running code. Maybe something I could specify in `AndroidManifest.xml` file to run, just poking here and here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement your own `Application` class and register it in you `AndroidManifest.xml`. You can then run initialization in the application's `onCreate()` method.

You can find more information [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class).

Comment: there's an issue, under limitations and warnings, `The application object is not guaranteed to stay in memory forever, it will get killed. `

Comment: `Android will create a new Application object and start the activity where the user was before to give the illusion that the application was never killed in the first place.`

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem, once `Application` gets killed and is re-instantiated, static block is ran again which I don't want

Comment: they article gave two suggestions, 1. Intent (but activities that send intents gets killed too), 2. Persist data to disk (it's not a static data), its programmed/executed stuff.

Comment: You won't be able to avoid the app/activity getting killed but won't happen unless your app is backgrounded and the OS determines it needs to free-up memory for other processes. If you're worried about data persistence you can use either use local storage as you mentioned or save your data in `onSaveInstanceState` `Bundle`. 
If you app does get killed, run re-initialization (could use a `Singleton`) and then re-load you data as needed.

Comment: It's not a static data for bundle, just some executions on the fly, I've another idea, what if I create a simple class, `public class LiveForever {}` and have static fields and static initializer on it that will be executed as soon as some `Activity` accesses them, will this class `LiveForever` gets killed too? It's not even an activity class or even registered in the manifest?

Comment: my concern is for the class `LiveForever` to die while the app is running, not persisting data. If the app is backgrounded and comes back alive again fresh and whole thing is re-ran then I've no problem. the requirement is one-time static initialization on each startup (no persisting data between sessions or startups)

Comment: Any objects previously instantiated are garbage-collected when an `Activity` gets killed and thus it needs to be re-created.

Comment: so if class `LiveForever` is being referenced by two activities, 2nd activity dies but first activity is still running on screen, `LiveForever` won't be garbage collected. 2nd case, app goes to background and everything is garbage collected included `LiveForever` and then the app is resumed and first activity is ran, the `LiveForever` will come back again. Is my assumption true? then this will solve the problem.

Comment: You're correct, however, assuming you only need one instance of `LiveForever` I would suggest instantiating it in your `Application` class, otherwise you will have two separate instances per activity. Then you can get a reference to it from your activities.

Comment: oh just to clear, no instantiation for `LiveForever`, it's just there for static fields and static initializer, common and shared for all activities. I guess I could do the same in Application class too but that warning threw me off, I just didn't want to get into a concrete class, just some static fields and a static initializer.